# simple html dom ahref first link

Tags: php

I need some help please, the html is this :

```
<div class="index_item index_item_ie"><a href="/watch-2757880-United-We- Fall-online-free" title="Watch United We Fall (2014)"><img src="//images.primewire.ag/thumbs/2757880_United_We_Fall_2014.jpg" border="0" width="150" height="225" alt="Watch United We Fall"><h2>United We Fall (2014)</h2></a><div class="index_ratings"><div id="unit_long2757880"><ul style="width: 100px;" class="unit-rating"><li style="width: 100px;" class="current-rating">Current rating.</li><li class="r1-unit"></li><li class="r2-unit"></li><li class="r3-unit"></li><li class="r4-unit"></li><li class="r5-unit"></li></ul></div></div>
<div class="item_categories"><a href="/?genre=Comedy">Comedy</a> </div></div>
```

I try to grab only the first link `/watch-2757880-United-We-Fall-online-free`

but returned all links

```
$ret =  $html->find('div.index_item');

foreach($ret as $elements) {
    foreach($elements->find('a') as $link) {
        $url = $link->href;
        echo $url;
    }
}
```

how to get the first link only ? `/watch-2757880-United-We-Fall-online-free`

Comment: it's a foreach loop. if you only want the first result, then `break` out of the loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To stop a `foreach`, use `break` You can do `break N` (i.e. `break 2;` in your case) to break more than one foreach at a time. http://php.net/break

Alternatively, put this logic in a function, and `return $url;` rather than echoing it.

Comment: Can you give me a example to mai case please ?

Comment: @MegaImdb Just `break 2;` after echoing the URL.